# How to abort created coroutine python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

How do I abort a created coroutine instance? My use case is a function taking in a coroutine and conditionally creating a tracked task for it (so that all of them could be `gather`ed later).

Ignoring it (not `await`ing it directly or indirectly) works, but gives a `RuntimeWarning`. I'd be OK with a solution that suppresses this warning.

Creating a task then immediately cancelling it starts its execution and the cancellation leads to other issues so it's not workable.

Checking the condition before the coroutines are created works, but damages maintainability since the same check for condition has to be in all the places before this function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.close()` method:

```
async def foo():
    pass
x = foo()
x.close()
```

Program finishes fine, no warnings.

Comment: Thanks, where did you find this? I couldn't see it in the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine

Comment: Is async def a keyword? How does that work? never seen that

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde yes, it is a new keyword, introduced in python 3.5, together with `async for`, `async with` and `await`. see here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-def

Comment: @LemonPi `close` and other methods on coroutine objects are documented at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects